# Cannot read property 'some field in an object' of undefined in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

in a component of my website with react and redux i'm using axios for to sent a request and the response is an array of objects.
and when i wanna use the property of objects in that array i get this error: Cannot read property 'courseName' of undefined
Dashboard.render

this is my component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { getCourses } from '../../actions/coursesActions';

    class Dashboard extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCourses();
      }

      render() {
        const { user } = this.props.auth;
        const { courses, loading } = this.props.course;
        return (
          <div>
            <p>Dashboard: {user.name}</p>
            <div className="card text-center">  
               {courses[1].courseTeacher}// i get the error here
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    Dashboard.propTypes = {
      getCourses: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      course: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      course: state.course,
      auth: state.auth
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCourses })(Dashboard);
```

when i console.log the courses array i get the array but when i console.log(courses.length) or console.log(courses[0]) i get errors

my courses array is like:

```
[
  {
    students: Array(1),
    _id: "5d24aec630fe2799dd28b554",
    courseName: "aaa",
    courseTeacher: "aaa",
    courseDetails: "review",
   …}
  {
    students: Array(0),
    _id: "5d24af81e01d9599f4f4384a",
    courseName: "a",
    courseTeacher: "aaa",
    courseDetails: "review",
  …}
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your initial state of the object but it seems like `loading` is not set inside the array. Also Axios returns it's value asynchronously, but the component will be rendered before the response was set inside redux. So you're accessing an empty object.
My approach is to have a loading state inside the component and use conditional rendering:

```
 class Dashboard extends Component {

      state = {
        loading: true,
      }

      componentDidMount() {
         this.initComponent()
      }

      initComponent = async () => {
        await this.props.getCourses();
        this.setState({loading: false})
      }

      render() {
        const { user } = this.props.auth;
        const { courses } = this.props.course;
        const { loading } = this.state
        return (
          <div>
            <p>Dashboard: {user.name}</p>
            {!loading && (
              <div className="card text-center">  
                 {courses[1].courseTeacher}// i get the error here
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

With this the courses first rendered when they are loaded. Maybe you're setting the loading flag inside your redux store. Then you don't need the local state and get it from the store but use it for conditional rendering anyways. Also you can show a spinner or an overlay while loading with `{loading && (...)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the data to reach your component, you can display a message in the meantime. Have you tried something like this? It also displays errors?

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCourses();
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const { courses, loading } = this.props.course;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Dashboard: {user.name}</p>
        <div className="card text-center">
          {!!(courses[1]) && courses[1].courseTeacher} // Just hide empty values
        </div>
        <div className="card text-center">
          {courses.length > 0 ? courses[1].courseName : 'No data'} // Show a message
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```